# Re-generate youtube-dl downloaded.txt

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

I used youtube-dl download youtube m4a files

```
youtube-dl --download-archive downloaded.txt --match-filter 'duration > 1200' -cit -f 140 'httplink'
```

but I had accidentialy deleted the downloaded.txt. I try to regenerate the downloaded.txt file with

```
for n in *.m4a
do 
    if [[ "$n" =~ -[-_0-9a-zA-Z]{11}.m4a$ ]]
       then echo "youtube ${n: -15: 11}" >> downloaded.txt
    fi
done
```

but it doesn't work since many file name are long and with non-ASCII characters e.g. CJK characters,  ▶, emoji characters. Any good suggestion to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Youtube-dl has a `--restrict-filenames` option to use only ASCII characters, try using that from now on. You can also keep the titles shorter by specifying the output file name template, I use `-o '%(title)s.%(ext)s`.

Answer (score 0):

Konichiwa in USA I dont think we are free to DL youtube videos. I wish there was a youtube playlist to iso automated service or script.

for the longfile name
try the `tr -d [set1] [set2]` to delete unwanted characters
or `tr -t [set1] [set2]` to truncated

```
7. Remove all non-printable character from a file
The following command can be used to remove all non-printable characters from a file.
$ tr -cd [:print:] < file.txt
```

above line taken from https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/linux-tr-command/

Im not sure about this line and perhaps you can replace the youoldList part with cat yourFile or echo "foobar"

```
then tr -cd [:print:] < youroldList.txt > downloaded.txt
```

sed is the stream editor command do man sed to learn about it
the -e command lets you run sed scripts which are formated likeso "s_replaceThis_withThis_;s/.m4a.*/./\"

the underscores and///\ part could be written just as instead "s///"

**SCRIPT ERRORS**

Also in your script there's an error with '>>' instead of '>' and the $n if this evaluates like $(false) or $(0) it will restart the ba$h and inject your data stream. [memory leak perhaps??] Maybe that happens at ${n: -15: 11}

Do you get an error like $(0)?

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in one directory, you can simply select them all in a Nautilus window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, copy the file names (including paths) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>then open Text Editor and paste the path + all file names into a text file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

If you don't want the path info before the file names on each line, use "Search > Find and Replace..." to remove it. Use the path characters as the search term and leave the replace field blank.